# Why can't I upload pics on certain sites

Tags: ios, ipad, ipados

I can't upload pictures on sites from my iPad 2 . I was trying to upload a picture of a part that I needed and it would let me .

Answer (score 1):

Mobile safari before iOS 6 does not have access to data from the camera roll or photo application by design.

iOS doesn't have a common space to store files like computer users have come to expect. Instead, each app is "sandboxed" and can only see the data it created/downloaded. Apple provides API for one program to request data from another. Mobile Safari would need to have hooks to allow a web site to ask to use the photo chooser for image upload to work. So the design makes it hard to upload files in the way most web sites expect on iOS.

The best you can do is use another app like the flickr app to push photos to the internet and then link back or upload from a URL. It's clumsy but works without you waiting for [mobile safari to change or updating to iOS 6.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399870)

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload files from any iOS device because apps can't access files from other apps. Since shared files, such as the photo library, are available from all apps, Apple could have chosen to let you upload photos, but for whatever reason they decided it was better to not have uploads at all.

Comment: Apple has made clear to developers that apps are sandboxed is primarily for security and secondarily for stability/performance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this new app:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webuploader/id448687892?mt=8

That is the center app you want

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jerry! Can you please add more information about WebUploader? How does it answer the OP's question?

Comment: Welcome to the site @Shanika - It's best to upvote/mark as helpful things you find useful on the site. Both you and Jerry need more reputation before you can comment and do other useful things on the site.